# Scene2d: InputListener does not call touchUp

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I have tried using an `InputListener` on an Actor but it seems that the touchUp does not get called. Every other method does work for me.

```
stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());

Widget actor = new Widget();
actor.setFillParent(true);
actor.addListener(new InputListener() {
    public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        Gdx.app.log("", "");
    }
});
stage.addActor(actor);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());

    Widget actor = new Widget();
    actor.setFillParent(true);
    actor.addListener(new InputListener() {

        @Override
        public void touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            Gdx.app.log("", "");
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(actor);


    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```